# Prove that complex modulus has no primitive

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

After having done a (small) course on complex analysis from a "physics point of view", I'm now doing a larger course on it from a mathematical perspective. However, early on in my lecture notes, it was casually remarked that |z|, the complex modulus, had no primitive function. However, I don't exactly see why this has to be the case.

It's very easy to find a primitive for the real modulus (absolute value), by writing |f| = sign(f)*f, but of course this doesn't work in complex numbers. Is there some theorem I can use to prove this, or use some fact about path-(in)dependency of complex integrals?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only analytic functions can have a primitive (in the complex sense).

Assume that $F' = f$. By assumption $F$ is  analytic, since $F'$ exists, but this will force $f$ to be analytic as well, since the derivative of an analytic function is analytic.

(You can also argue more or less like you did: If $f$ has a primitive, then the integral of $f$ over any closed curve is $0$. Try to find a closed curve $C$ such that $\int_C |z|\,dz \neq 0$.)